# How do click to a href with javascript?

Tags: javascript, events

I Want do a click to an existing `<a href="">`

Code :

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
    var el = els[i];
    if (el.href === 'https://www.messenger.com/t/someperson') {
        el.click;
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `click` as a function: `el.click()`. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`el.click` is a function, you have to call it:

`el.click();`

Comment: Thank you very much just what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `window.location`

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
    var el = els[i];
    if (el.href === 'https://www.messenger.com/t/someperson') {
        window.location = el.href;
    }
}
```

Comment: well this would work untill you need to do some javascript when the link is clicked..

Comment: I wonder then why it does not work `document.getElementsByTagName('a').click();`

Comment: Thanks but this only makes me redirect to that url, what I wanted was to click so it was el.click ();

Comment: well `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` returns an array and an array does not have a methon `click()`. So this works `document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click();` not that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
        var el = els[i];
        if (el.href === 'https://www.messenger.com/t/someperson') {

           el.click();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much appreciate your help

Comment: mention not. don't forget to mark it as answer and to vote it if it solved your problem.